# Openshift error during database setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, openshift

I get this error whenever i run
`RAILS_ENV=production rake db:setup`

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/var/lib/openshift/55bb37e82d5271756a00006c/app-root/runtime/repo/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/openshift/55bb37e82d5271756a00006c/app-root/runtime/repo/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/openshift/55bb37e82d5271756a00006c/app-root/runtime/repo/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What could the solution be? Thanks.

Comment: `bundle exec rake db:setup RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: `Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources`
`Run bundle install to install missing gems.`

That is the result I got

Comment: `gem list rake` if many rake versions are installed, uninstall them and then use `bundle install` to install gems